# Excel - Highlight cells that matches current day of any date

Tags: excel

Looking for a way to highlight Current Day of any date to be highlighted.

[image]

here is a little example, different dates,i just want to highlight todays date (its 26) so 26 should highlight no matter whats the month is.

[image]
little effort i made.. but it doesn't work

Comment: `=Today` might do the trick

Comment: So you're saying that the last 3 cells should all be highlighted (Jul 26, Aug 26, Sept 26)?

Comment: @Zack yes thats correct

Answer (score 2):

You can use `=DAY()` to get the current day number back and `=TODAY()` to get today's date.

So, in your case, your conditional formatting formula in cell `A1` would be `DAY(A1)=DAY(TODAY())`, then you can copy and paste the formatting down.

Comment: You can also apply the conditional formatting all at once: Just make sure to use relative cell references, as Jonathon has (no dollar signs).